# Did html spec require focus fire after mousedown?

Tags: html, dom-events

Or it's just every browser happen to implement same behaviour? Only place I found in [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-click) is in click event section which says

> If the event target is focusable, the default action MUST be to give that element document focus.

But actually focus is the default action of mousedown event, which is widely used in today's frontend development, so I'd like to know why

Comment: Use this link i hope its helps you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the answer in the very quote you've posted?

> **If** the event target is **focusable**, the default action **MUST** be to **give** that element document ***focus***.

And then https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-focus

> 4.2.4.2. **`focus`**
>   ...
>   A user agent **MUST** dispatch this event when an event target receives ***focus***.

In other words: the spec indeed **requires** `focus` event to be fired when and if an element receives *focus*

By the way, the `focus` as event and *focus* as a property - is two different things.

**But!.. The quote is actually from [`click`](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-click) event, not from `mousedown`**

And if you test it in browsers you'll see that:

1. They behave differently (at least mine *Chrome 81* and *FF 75*).
   If you click inside `<textarea>`, but move out an only then release the button *Chrome* won't send `click` to the `<textarea>`, but *FF* will
2. But they give *focus* to `<textarea>` and fire `focus` event right after `mousedown`.

So that probably means, that:

1. **No** the spec doesn't require `focus` event to be fired after `mousedown`. (Instead it requires it to be fired after `click`)
2. **Yes** it's just so happens that every browser (well... at least those two I've tested) implement same *non-standard* behavior

Answer (score 1):

So far the only thing I found in [spec](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-mousedown) is

> Many implementations use the mousedown event to begin a variety of contextually dependent default actions. These default actions can be prevented if this event is canceled. Some of these default actions could include: beginning a drag/drop interaction with an image or link, starting text selection, etc. Additionally, some implementations provide a mouse-driven panning feature that is activated when the middle mouse button is pressed at the time the mousedown event is dispatched.

Although it didn't explicitly says focus, I guess it's still enough evidence